# Implicit Differentiation and relativity: Speed of a plane

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, implicit-differentiation

How to solve the following question?
If a plane follows the curve $y=f(x)$, and its ground speed is $\frac{dx}{dt} = 500mph$, how fast is the plane going up? How fast is the plane going?

My attempt:
I drew a triangle such that height is $f(x)$ and the base is $x$. The hypotenuse line is z. Since $y = f(x)$, I know that 
$$\frac{df}{dt}=\frac{df}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}$$.
$$\frac{df}{dt}=\frac{df}{dx}\cdot500$$
Therefore, the speed of plane going up is $\frac{df}{dx}\cdot500$. Next, I use the phytagoras theorem where $z^2 = x^2 + y^2$. This leads to:
$$z^2 = x^2 + f(x)^2$$
Here, I applied implicit differentiation.
$$2z\frac{dz}{dt} = 2x\frac{dx}{dt}+2f(x)\frac{df}{dt}$$
$$\frac{dz}{dt} = \frac{x\frac{dx}{dt}+f(x)\frac{df}{dt}}{z}$$
Substitute the previously obtained "$\frac{df}{dt}$" and predefined $\frac{dx}{dt} = 500$
$$\frac{dz}{dt} = \frac{x\cdot500+f(x)\frac{df}{dx}\cdot500}{z}$$
$$= \frac{500\cdot (x+f(x)\frac{df}{dx})}{z}$$
This is the best I could get. The answer is $500\sqrt{1+(\frac{df}{dx})^2}$ but how to obtain it?

Comment: I think you could take derivatives before applying Pythoagoras. Whatever the momentary change in $z$ is, it's the hypotenuse of the triangle spanned by the momentary change in $x$ and the momentary change in $f$ as legs.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks for the comment. But I don't get what you mean. Can you illustrate the first few steps? Maybe i'll get an idea then I can follow through. :)

Comment: What I mean is just that $\left(\frac{dz}{dt}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{df}{dt}\right)^2$. Now take the square root, and you should be able to get to your answer. Also note that my $z$ is different form your $z$. My $z$ is distance along the graph, not distance from the origin (which is what you have when you use a triangle with base $x$ and height $f(x)$).

Comment: @Arthur Alright. I got the answer but I don't understand why $\frac{dz}{dt}^2 = \frac{dx}{dt}^2 + \frac{df}{dt}^2$ is applicable. Does it work for other equations as well? I mean like if $Z^3 = X^6 + Y^7$ (arbitrary function), then  $\frac{dz}{dt}^3 = \frac{dx}{dt}^6 + \frac{df}{dt}^7$? In addition, do you mean your z moves along the curve rather a linear slope?

Comment: What I mean by "$z$ is distance along the graph" is, in this case, interpreted as "$z(t)$ is the total distance the plane has travelled by time $t$". This is usually not a very simple quantity to work with, but we can reason about how it changes over very small time scales (and thus about its derivative) by using the Pythagorean theorem. And it is true that for any function $g(x)$, the pythagorean relationship between $\frac{dx}{dt}, \frac{dg}{dt}$ and $\frac{dz}{dt}$ holds, _provided_ that we define $z$ as I have done.

Comment: Hi @Arthur Can you explain why the derivatives before applying Pythagorean is true in the first place? I still can't find the justification for $\frac{dz}{dt}^2 = \frac{dx}{dt}^2 + \frac{df}{dt}^2$.

Comment: Because for a _tiny_ change $\Delta t$ in $t$, the graph looks like a straight line. We want the corresponding length $\Delta z$, and what we have do work with is $\Delta x$ and $\Delta f$, which make up two legs of a right triangle, and our tiny bit of graph is very close to being the hypotenuse of that triangle. Thus $(\Delta z)^2\approx(\Delta x)^2+(\Delta f)^2$. We divide on both sides by $(\Delta t)^2$, because we are allowed to do that an because we know what we want in the end. Lastly, the approximation gets better as $\Delta t\to 0$, so we do that and everything becomes derivatives.